# Reading with fread in Assembly x86-64 AT&T

Tags: assembly, buffer, fread

I am writing B to the file and then I am trying to read the first byte of the file, which is B, and write it again to the file. But, when I am writing, after reading from the file, it prints 0x00, because the value which was read is not stored in the buffer. The writing is fine, but the reading is not. What might be wrong here? Thank you!

```
.section .bss

buffer: .skip 100

      .align 8
file: .quad 0


.data

B: .byte 0x42
.text
filename: .asciz "file.bmp"
mode: .asciz "w"
myText: .asciz "C"
toInt: .asciz "%u"




.global main

main:
    pushq   %rbp            
    movq    %rsp, %rbp      
    
    movq $filename , %rdi      
    movq $mode , %rsi         
    call fopen        

    mov %rax, file 

    mov $B, %rdi 
    mov $1, %rsi 
    mov $1, %rdx 
    mov file, %rcx 
    call fwrite

    mov file, %rdi 
    mov $0, %rsi 
    mov $0, %rdx 
    call fseek 

    mov $buffer, %rdi 
    mov $1, %rsi 
    mov $1, %rdx 
    mov file, %rcx 
    call fread

    mov $buffer, %rdi 
    mov $1, %rsi 
    mov $1, %rdx 
    mov file, %rcx 
    call fwrite

    mov file, %rdi 
    call fclose

    movq    %rbp, %rsp     
    popq    %rbp            
    movq    $0, %rdi        
    call    exit
```

Comment: You opened the file for writing only. You can not read from it. Change the `"w"` to `"w+"`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I also have this problem that I am trying to xor the byte read from the file with an integer. I am doing this:  movq $5, %r10, xor %r10, $buffer, because I want to write back to the file the result from xor. But I get mismatch operand. Do you have any idea how to solve this? Appreciate very much

Comment: I also tried doing this:   movq $5, %r10 
    xor $buffer, %r10

    mov %r10, %rdi 
    mov $1, %rsi 
    mov $1, %rdx 
    mov file, %rcx 
    call fwrite, but its writing 0x00

Comment: You want `xorb $5, buffer`. You do not want the `$` as that signals an immediate.

Comment: @Jester: Actually `"r+"` for `open(O_RDRW)`; `"w+"` includes `O_TRUNC` so you don't want that for reading an existing file!  If the OP had single-stepped with a debugger, or use `ltrace` or `strace`, they'd have seen which library function calls (or system calls) were failing.

Comment: Since the code was using `w` I assumed the truncation was intended. But otherwise, yeah, you are of course right :)